# Unitize matrix above certain threshold

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I would like to unitize a matrix with the function `Unitize` above a certain threshold, which either can be set "freely" or defined through a `Quantile` function or alike.

Here a data example:

```
{{1.99719*10^7, 66451.9, 84170.3, 57308.1, 13392.5, 16138.1}, 
{130243., 1.21641*10^7, 61228.3, 66902.9, 53069.1, 30019.1}, 
{67442.3, 41337., 3.56545*10^6, 12429.4, 6761.89, 5113.16}, 
{41831., 50735.4, 12394.5, 2.61964*10^6, 35691.6, 55169.1}, 
{22010.3, 39714.9, 6125.92, 55680.6, 2.0344*10^6, 36440.}, 
{21711.1, 41355.9, 4325.26, 79821.2, 33668.8, 1.87212*10^6}}
```

Now I would like to `Unitize` every value, say above 50k and set every other value to zero in the matrix. Does someone tell me how to tackle the problem?

Comment: Subtract the threshold value before using `Unitize`.  `Unitize[matrix-threshold]`.

Comment: Simple but efficient. :D Thank you very much for your immediate reply! Did not think about that. I replaced the negative values using the following formula `Replace[abcd, zero_ /; zero < 0 -> 0, {2}]`. Hope this is correct and might be useful for people trying to solve the same problem. :)

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question.  I think you want `UnitStep`, not `Unitize`.  I was certainly thinking `UnitStep` when I wrote `Unitize` in my comment (with `Unitize` it makes little sense).  Try `UnitStep[matrix - threshold]`.  There is also `Clip`.

Answer (score 2):

as suggested by @Szabolcs

```
{{1.99719*10^7, 66451.9, 84170.3, 57308.1, 13392.5, 16138.1}, 
{130243., 1.21641*10^7, 61228.3, 66902.9, 53069.1, 30019.1}, 
{67442.3, 41337., 3.56545*10^6, 12429.4, 6761.89, 5113.16}, 
{41831., 50735.4, 12394.5, 2.61964*10^6, 35691.6, 55169.1}, 
{22010.3, 39714.9, 6125.92, 55680.6, 2.0344*10^6, 36440.}, 
{21711.1, 41355.9, 4325.26, 79821.2, 33668.8, 1.87212*10^6}}
//Clip[#, {49999, 50000}, {0, 1}] &

(* {{1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0,
1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1}} *)
```